# Titanic Statistical Application

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception, filereader

I'm having a hard time figuring out why only parts of my code are working.I'm pulling from a txt file to provide data that answers the questions the user prompts to answer. this is my error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at TestTitanic.filler(TestTitanic.java:13) at TestTitanic.main(TestTitanic.java:41)
>
> C:\Users\Jznica Sabatini\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>
> Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Here are lines 13, 41, and I'm putting in 53, even though I'm not sure what that error is.

```
line 13    String content = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))
line 41    runner.filler(args);
```

So i have a test class (where the above examples are from, a titanic class, and although probably unnecessary, a sub class to the the titanic with an extends method but it all compiled, its just that when i compile in the cmd line and the test class runs with the titanic.txt file as cmd ln args only 3 of the 7 questions when user prompts a response actually print.

The following is my TestTitanic class. I was using netbeans and allowing to change it via the suggestions and now I dont even get my cmd ln to print the questions or prompt the user to input their response. In net beans it says my test class is where my errors are, but given the number of some of the lines erroring in my cmd line i know it's my original Titanic parent class but for now I'll start with the smaller errors.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestTitanic {

    // Method that builds a 2D array from the txt file
    public void filler(String[] args) {

        // Try-catch is needed for passing args to method
        try {
            // Turns the txt file into one large string
            String content = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                    .useDelimiter("\\Z") // To the end of the file
                    .next();
            String[] rows = content.split("\n"); // Breaks up by new line
            // Creates a 2D array as "long" as the input file
            String[][] titanic = new String[rows.length][];

            // Fills the 2D array
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                titanic[i] = rows[i].split("\\t");
            }

            // Creates a new Titanic object
            Titanic titanicObject = new Titanic(titanic);
            // Calls the passToMenu method from Titanic class
            titanicObject.passToMenu();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an object from this class
        TestTitanic runner = new TestTitanic();
        // Calls the program method to fill the array
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runner.filler(args);
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Line 13 does not have a semicolon at the end! Also, please enclose your code lines with <code> and </code>.

Comment: Any reason to why you are making a new thread inside of your main thread? It doesn't seem like you intend to multi-thread. In addition: "...I was using netbeans and allowing to change it via the suggestions" <- that way lies madness, only take the suggestions if you understand them.

Comment: so i fixed it and am back to the original problem of typing in my response to a question and receiving multiple outofbounds errors depending on which question i choose to answer.
<code> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Titanic.perishedPercent(Titanic.java:40)
//line 40 if (row[1].equals("0")) { </code>
This is just one of many examples from just one of the errors but again if you want to see more I'll be more than happy to supply it for a better understanding.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the code you supplied above has any major issues I could catch. Now you seem to be talking about a different part of code all together?

Comment: To `getCodeFormattingLikeThis();` use the " ` " character, the button with " ~ " on it. For multi line code highlight the code and click the " { } " button or tab the section over with eight spaces per line. (multi line code does not work in comments)

Comment: (if only there was a way to upload documents as i essentially have four and that way it would be easier to explain the issue im having)
my apologies i meant to put this line for the error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`
`at TestTitanic.filler(TestTitanic.java:28)`

Comment: *****`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`
`at TestTitanic.filler(TestTitanic.java:28)`
//line 28 `titanicObject.passToMenu();`
`at TestTitanic.main(TestTitanic.java:41)`
//line 41 `runner.filler(args);`******

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105456/discussion-between-kiro-yakuza-and-3monkeys1gorilla).

Answer (score 0):

You might not be providing command line argument to your program hence getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` at

`String content = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));`

Since you are using Netbeans IDE you can pass command line argument the program as :
 [using-command-line-arguments-in netbeans](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html)

[pass-command-line-arguments-netbeans-ide](http://www.cprogramto.com/pass-command-line-arguments-netbeans-ide/)